# Converting all the datetime columns of a variable Pandas DataFrame into a different timezone

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I have to deal with a Pandas DataFrame that can be composed by different datetime columns (they can vary, I can have 0..N datetime cols). I know that each datetime column timezone is UTC and I need to convert their data to another timezone. If I do as follows:

```
df['a_datetime_column'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('my_timezone')
```

it works but I need to know in advance the datetime column names (ok, I could get them in some way).

Is there a specific way to do this conversion on all the DataFrame at once independently from the composition of its columns?

Comment: What do you have when you print `df.dtypes`? Can you filter those with `datetime` type from there?

Comment: For the datetime cols I have `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: then you can simply loop over the columns with type datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the columns which have datetime type:

```
for col,dtyp in df.dtypes.iteritems():
    if dtyp == 'datetime64[ns]':
        df[col] = df[col].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('my_timezone')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), you can use it to select only the `datetime64[ns]` columns and apply your `tz_convert` to those:

```
df.select_dtypes(inlcude=["datetime64[ns]"]).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('my_timezone')
```

Comment: Does this require starting data being tz aware?

Comment: What do you mean? If they are of type `datetime64[ns]` I assume they have some sort of timezone no?

Comment: For the selection part, no.